# nested loop to display all data from models django

Tags: python, django

I need to display all data from models in Django

I have two list one has all rows and another has all columns, what is want to do something like

```
{{student.username }}
```

I am trying to use nested loop to get all data, I know this "row.{{column}} " is wrong but did not find the solutions

```
 {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in columns %}
          <td>{{ row.{{column}} }}</td>

       {% endfor %}
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

can any one guide me how to use like this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the `student` and fetch only the required `columns` using `values_list`

**Ex:**

```
student = student.objects.values_list('column_1', 'column_2')
```

Then in your template

```
 {% for column in student %}
    <tr>
          <td>{{ column }} }}</td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)**